# Delete dictionary values if they are present in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a Python set

```
A = {34, 4, 7, 39, 40, 13, 18, 20}
```

and a dictionary

```
B = {4: [6, 34, 39], 7: [18, 34], 13: [6, 18, 34], 18: [7, 13], 
     20: [31, 47], 34: [4, 7, 13], 39: [4, 8], 40: [15, 43]}
```

I want to create a new dictionary C such that if any of the values in B contains a number in A, then they must be removed from the corresponding value list. Keys should be unaffected.

For example, the desired output that I am looking for is:

```
C = {4: [6], 7: [], 13: [6], 18: [], 20: [31, 47], 34: [], 39: [8]}
```

I tried to solve this using the following code:

```
C = {}
for key, value in B_mod.items():
    if value in A:
        C[key] = value
print("C is:", C)
```

The output that I am getting is as follows:

```
C is: {7: 18, 18: 7, 34: 4, 39: 4}
```

Clearly, it is not working.

*Please note that `B_mod` means that I am unlisting the list in values of dictionary B using the code:

```
B_mod = {k:v[0] for k,v in B.items()} # Unlisitng the values of dictionary B
```

I did this because I could not iterate through lists as values in B.*

Any help to get C?

Comment: Why don't you expect to have `40: [15, 43]` in your output dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can iterate through the lists in the values of `B`, indeed, you need to, so something like this:

```
>>> A = {34, 4, 7, 39, 40, 13, 18, 20}
>>> B = {4: [6, 34, 39], 7: [18, 34], 13: [6, 18, 34], 18: [7, 13], 20: [31, 47], 34: [4, 7, 13], 39: [4, 8], 40: [15, 43]}
>>> C = {}
>>> for key, value in B.items():
...     new_value = []
...     for val in value:
...         if val not in A:
...             new_value.append(val)
...     C[key] = new_value
...
>>> C
{4: [6], 7: [], 13: [6], 18: [], 20: [31, 47], 34: [], 39: [8], 40: [15, 43]}
>>>
```

You can also use a dictionary comprehension with a list comprehension:

```
>>> {k:[v for v in vs if v not in A] for k, vs in B.items()}
{4: [6], 7: [], 13: [6], 18: [], 20: [31, 47], 34: [], 39: [8], 40: [15, 43]}
```

Which is the equivalent of the for-loop approach. Whichever makes more sense to you is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your first method works! However, the one liner just returns an empty dictionary. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @SayantaSeth no, it absolutely does *not* return an empty dictionary. This is the output from my interpreter session. If you are getting an empty dictionary, you are using different code (most likely, whatever `B` is is empty, instead of the `B` I defined above)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of a dictionary and list comprehensions:

```
>>> {k: [i for i in v if i not in A] for k, v in B.items()}
{4: [6], 7: [], 13: [6], 18: [], 20: [31, 47], 34: [], 39: [8], 40: [15, 43]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line with this dictionary and list comprehension:

```py
C = {k: [x for x in v if x not in A] for k, v in B.items()}
```